# iOS Facebook sdk open album select and image select screens

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

So basically i want a way to open a screen with my Facebook albums. I should be able to select 
   an album and then a screen with the images in that album should open and after selecting the image i 
    should get it's url or data. I think theres a way to do that with the Facebook sdk and by that i
  mean that i don't have to create the albums/images screens they are already in the sdk but how
 do i use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Facebook SDK don't have this feature.

There are some interesting projects on github for example: https://github.com/bradtheappguy/BSFacebookImagePicker